# Is SSH and remote server config safe on public wifi?

Tags: security, ssh

I need to get out of this apartment and see other human beings. I'd like to go to the local coffee shop to do my server configuration through SSH. I might also be using FTP. Is this safe?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

SSH yes, FTP no. As a bonus, HTTP is only safe if you use it over HTTPS. You can use [SCP](http://amath.colorado.edu/computing/software/man/scp.html) or [SFTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SSH_File_Transfer_Protocol) to transfer files securely to hosts which are already running SSH though.

Just don't use a 90's version of SSH and you will be fine.

Comment: When you say 90's version of SSH, what do you mean? I'm currently using PuTTY to log in.

Comment: The latest version of PUTTY will be fine, provided that your server is also within the last ten years and a default SSH setup was used (if you don't know that it wasn't, then you are okay). Also, yes you will want to use SCP or a Windows SSH client that supports file transfers instead of FTP. I think Filezilla supports SFTP, so that should be sufficient.

Comment: @Nick 90's as in "not released before the year 2000" :), as @johnnie said

Answer (score 0):

to be extra safe, setup key based authentication between yourself and your server.  It will not connect if there is a man in the middle of the transaction, giving you much more security.

Comment: This is safer, but if there's a MITM attack in progress SSH will warn him about the remote host identification key changing even if he is using only password auth.